# jquery function to Hide webgrid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with asp .net MVC3 to hover selected columns.There is a grid,Multiselect Listbox and a button in a page.I am using the following webgrid to display table.

```
  @{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.oTravelReadyEntities, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 3);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:"WebGrid",
headerStyle:"Header",
alternatingRowStyle:"alt",
columns:grid.Columns(
grid.Column("Var_AssoId", "Var_AssoId", canSort: true, format: @<b>@item.Var_AssoId</b>,style:"Number"),
grid.Column("Var_AssociateName", "Var_AssociateName"),
grid.Column("Var_Grade", "Var_Grade"),
grid.Column("Char_VirtualPool", "Char_VirtualPool"),
grid.Column("Var_VirtualPoolCatagory", "Var_VirtualPoolCatagory"),
grid.Column("Char_VisaUtilization", "Char_VisaUtilization"),
grid.Column("Var_SupervisorId", "Var_SupervisorId"),
grid.Column("Var_SupervisorName", "Var_SupervisorName"),
grid.Column("Var_Deparment", "Var_Deparment"),
grid.Column("Var_Vertical", "Var_Vertical"),
grid.Column("Var_AccountName", "Var_AccountName"),
grid.Column("Var_Project_Desc", "Var_Project_Desc")
));
```

}

At runtime i'll select the column names from the multiple listbox which is placed under webgrid after selecting ColumnNames when i click the show button, the webgrid should show only the selected columns,Other columns should be hided.how can i do it using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just try to use jQuery addClass() method on the fly, for example, to hide a DIV element,

jQuery

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#notice").addClass("divcls");    
});
```

CSS

```
.divcls{display:none;}
```

for fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ablealias/Xd6qM/